# Create specific error message in javascript validation scheme

Tags: javascript

I was looking for a way to elegantly validate properties on a javascript object and came across this solution made by Patrick Roberts:

[Javascript - elegant way to check object has required properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38616612/javascript-elegant-way-to-check-object-has-required-properties)

```
const schema = {
  name: value => /^([A-Z][a-z\-]* )+[A-Z][a-z\-]*( \w+\.?)?$/.test(value),
  age: value => parseInt(value) === Number(value) && value >= 18,
  phone: value => /^(\+?\d{1,2}-)?\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$/.test(value)
};

let info = {
  name: 'John Doe',
  age: '',
  phone: '123-456-7890'
};

const validate = (object, schema) => Object
  .keys(schema)
  .filter(key => !schema[key](object[key]))
  .map(key => new Error(`${key} is invalid.`));

const errors = validate(info, schema);

if (errors.length > 0) {
  for (const { message } of errors) {
    console.log(message);
  }
} else {
  console.log('info is valid');
}
```

This solution can only return a generic error message `return new Error(key + " is invalid")`

How could I modify this solution to give a more specific error message?

An example would be if the age on the info object was set to 17:

```
let info = {
  name: 'John Doe',
  age: '17',
  phone: '123-456-7890'
};
```

then the error message would be "Age must be above 18" and if it was set to 100, the error message would be "Age must be below 100"

Comment: Whether like this? https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/vYOxZWY