# How do I return false if my Object has an empty string anywhere?

Tags: javascript

I have an object like this:

```js
const obj = {
  id: '123abc',
  carrier_name: '',
  group_id: '',
  member_id: '',
  plan_name: '',
}
```

and I want to return `false` if any part of the object has an empty string. So for example:

```js
const obj = {
  id: '123abc',
  carrier_name: ''ABC,
  group_id: '123',
  member_id: 'xyz',
  plan_name: '',
}
```

The above would return false. Similarly if something like this is partially filled:

```js
const obj = {
  id: '123abc',
  carrier_name: ''ABC,
  group_id: '',
  member_id: 'xyz',
  plan_name: '',
}
```

This would return false.

I tried something manually like this:

```js
return obj.carrier_name.length === 0 || obj.group_id.length === 0 || obj.member_id.length === 0 || obj.plan_name.length === 0
```

but im wondering if there's any better way.

Comment: do you have only strings as values? can you have nested objects?

Comment: You may look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38616612/javascript-elegant-way-to-check-object-has-required-properties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) with [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```js
const obj = {
  id: '123abc',
  carrier_name: 'a',
  group_id: 'a',
  member_id: 'a',
  plan_name: 'a',
}

console.log(!Object.values(obj).some(val => val === ""))

const obj2 = {
  id: '123abc',
  carrier_name: '',
  group_id: 'a',
  member_id: 'a',
  plan_name: 'a',
}

console.log(!Object.values(obj2).some(val => val === ""))
```

Comment: You probably want to show inverting the result, since the OP is looking for `false` if there's a `""` present. Or, of course, `every(s => s !== "")`

Answer (score 3):

Simple loop and check

```js
const obj = {
  id: '123abc',
  carrier_name: 'a',
  group_id: 'a',
  member_id: '',
  plan_name: '',
}

const checkIfEmpty = obj => {
  for (const property in obj) {
    if (obj[property].length === 0) {
      return true
    }
  }
  return false
}

console.log(checkIfEmpty(obj))
```

Comment: You need to invert the results

Comment: Right, I didn't notice, I typed it blindly :)

Comment: This can cause a false positive if the value is an array

Comment: He didn't talk about an array @TravisJ

Answer (score 0):

You could check with `every` and `Boolean` as callback, **if you have only strings**.

```js
const check = object => Object.values(object).every(Boolean);

console.log(check({ foo: 'bar' }));          //  true
console.log(check({ foo: '' }));             // false
console.log(check({ foo: '', bar: 'baz' })); // false
console.log(check({ foo: '', bar: '' }));    // false
```

Comment: Using `Boolean` will also result in `false` for properties with `0` or other falsy values. *(not my downvote)*

Comment: @T.J.Crowder OP solution assumes values are always `string`s

Comment: Ah, true. But I wonder if that's one of the weaknesses of their solution...