# How can I check the values of an object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Use case: I have an http request represented by an object and I want to check the fields of the object before I make an http call with the request(i.e. makeHttpCall(request)). For example, given the object below:

```
{
  "classic": false,
  "billing-account": "1234567890",
  "device": "123456"
}
```

I want to validate the following fields from the object:

- "classic" is a bool true/false
- "billing-account" is a string with length 9
- "device" value is a string with length 6

I want to be able to write a config that can be used to validate the fields, similar PropTypes or Formik. For example:

```
{
  "classic": boolean
  "billing-account": string.length===9
  "device": string.length===9
}
```

UPDATE:
yup is what I was looking for https://github.com/jquense/yup

Comment: Show us what you have tried. SO isn't a free code writing service. The objective here is for you to post your attempts to solve your own issue and others help when they don't work as expected. See [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Common, well-tested, and very popular options include [joi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/joi) and [validatorjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/validatorjs).

Comment: You need to use functions in your example, like `classic: x => typeof x === "boolean"`. Next you can iterate over the keys and pass the values to the validator functions.

Comment: thank you @jarmond, I will look into these

Comment: Duplicate: [Javascript - elegant way to check object has required properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38616612/javascript-elegant-way-to-check-object-has-required-properties)

Answer (score 1):

You can make a function in order to validate each key as an if statement:

```js
const request1 = {
  "classic": false,
  "billing-account": "1234567890",
  "device": "123456"
}

const request2 = {
  "classic": false,
  "billing-account": "123456789",
  "device": "123456"
}


console.log(validate(request1));    // false

console.log(validate(request2));   // true

function validate(obj) {
  return typeof obj["classic"] === "boolean" && 
         obj["billing-account"].length === 9 && 
         obj["device"].length === 6;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is something I was looking for

Comment: This breaks for `"billing-account": 123456789`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a conditions object that has function attributes, then loop through the attributes and check the corresponding attribute in the object to validate.

```js
const obj = {
  "classic": false,
  "billing-account": "123456789",
  "device": "123456"
}

const conditions = {
  "classic": e => typeof e == "boolean",
  "billing-account": e => e.length == 9,
  "device": e => e.length == 6
}

function validate(s) {
  var isValid = true;
  Object.keys(s).forEach(e => isValid = !conditions[e](s[e]) ? false : isValid);
  return isValid;
}
console.log(validate(obj));
```

Comment: @ChrisG What made you say it breaks then?

Comment: @ChrisG That's not mentioned in the question, and that's not even the main thing the OP is having trouble with. I am assuming the asker already has the proper validation functions written, but they are only looking for how you can combine them together.

Comment: @ChrisG Also, it doesn't break, since `undefined` is not equal to `9`.

Comment: That is true, but it'll give a false result for something that isn't a string but has a length property of value `9`. To make sure it's a string, you need to use `typeof e === "string"` no matter how you slice it.