# Accessing dynamic properties of an Object in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, boolean

I’m checking whether there is a placeholder present in the “all” string within alertDetails object so my question is I need to access email,sms,fax property that appears dynamically based on user’s input (the code is a part of an alert box in which an user can choose to send alert via different delivery methods) so I saved all the possible delivery methods in an array and tried like below;

```
Const delmethod=[“email”,”sms”,”fax”]

for(let i=0;i<delmethod.length;i++)
{
Console.log(alertDetails &&
            alertDetails.alertMessage &&
            alertDetails.alertMessage[${lang}] &&
            alertDetails.alertMessage[${lang}].all
            ? alertDetails.alertMessage[${lang}][‘${delmethod(i)}’].includes('placeholder')
            : false;
   }
```

P.S:the property “all” is fixed it’s just the email fax will be changing based on user’s input, to sum it up I want to return true if “placeholder” exists in any of the strings(all,email,fax,sms) the method I tried just prints the del method array, I’d appreciate any help thanks!

Comment: This doesn't look like valid JavaScript. Please edit your question to make it syntactically correct JS code.

Comment: This is in react tho apologies for not making it clear, that console.log is written in that way to avoid “cannot read the undefined property” error  otherwise it’s plain like console.log(alertDetails.alertMessage.[${lang}].all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your code. You cannot just use `${lang}`. You must surround your string with backticks (`) if you want to use [template literals](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_string_templates.asp).

To access properties of an object you need a a key i.e. a string  which you already have so in this case template literals are not required at all.

When you access an array by index you need to use `[]` not `()`  so use `delmethod[i]` instead of `delmethod(i)`. Additionally make sure an [property exists on an JavaScript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38616612/javascript-elegant-way-to-check-object-has-required-properties).

```js
const delmethod = ["email", "sms", "fax"];

const alertDetails = {
  alertMessage: {
    en: {
      all: "emailsfsdfsdfsd",
      fax: "placeholder",
      sms: "sdkjföskjfsödkj"
    },
  },
};

const lang = "en";

for (let i = 0; i < delmethod.length; i++) {
  if (
    alertDetails &&
    alertDetails.alertMessage &&
    // use backticks ` when trying to use template literals
    alertDetails.alertMessage[`${lang}`] &&
    // there is actually no need for template literals here
    alertDetails.alertMessage[lang].all &&
    // you need to make sure "sms" or "fax" or "email" key actually exist on the object
    alertDetails.alertMessage[lang][delmethod[i]] &&
    alertDetails.alertMessage[lang][delmethod[i]].includes("placeholder")
  ) {
    console.log(
      `alertDetails.alertMessage[${lang}][${delmethod[i]}] does have a placeholder`
    );
    console.log(true);
  } else {
    console.log(
      `alertDetails.alertMessage[${lang}] does NOT have property ${delmethod[i]} or does NOT have a placeholder`
    );
    console.log(false);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but if we add the email sms fax properties oueselves there won't be a probelm when it gets automatically added when user chooses email and it gets added again? @Mushroomator